# sound recording and moving to next activity

Tags: android

I am newbie to android and trying to record voice using the MediaRecorder and creating the audio file also successfully. after that i had move to the next activity with button click there also no problem and playing the sound also successfully  but when i am moving to the previous activity from where i had come.it making all the class reference and variable as null  and saving the audiofile as null because i had to do the recording when the activity start.i had implement the strategy of singleton class but its class variable also getting null on coming back.For much description mentioning the code.

code for record in the oncreate() method.
//

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            setrecordtime = extras.getLong("RECORDTIME");
```

finding the record time here and after that starting the recording.
//

```
if (setrecordtime!=0&&setrecordtime < INFINITE) {

            startrecordbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            stoprecordbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            startrecording();
```

//startrecording method

```
private void startrecording() {

        myrecordaudiofile = getAudiofilemedia();
        if (myrecordaudiofile != null){
        myaudiorecoreder = new MediaRecorder();
        myaudiorecoreder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myaudiorecoreder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myaudiorecoreder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        myaudiorecoreder.setOutputFile(myrecordaudiofile.getAbsolutePath());

        try {
            myaudiorecoreder.prepare();
            myaudiorecoreder.start();


        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myrecordtextview.setText("RECORDING STARTED......");
        setRecordstatus(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO FILE TO RECORD", 0).show();
        }

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        stoprecording();
                        //myrecordtextview.setText("RECORDING...STATUS");
                    }
                });

            }
        }, setrecordtime);
    }
```

going to next screen and playing the sound
//

```
case R.id.preview_button1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, DisplayandPlay.class);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
```

on coming back from DisplayandPlay.class and after that saving the file but the audio file getting null.
thanks any suggestion to go with audiorecord class or stay with the mediarecorder only.

Comment: show code of running the file in  DisplayandPlay ... and just to clarify you are saving the file in sdcard in orig activity and when preview button is pressed you play it another activity named DisplayandPlay ? and when you come back from that activity that file saved in sdcard is null ?

Comment: just u have to call this function finish(); ratherthan intent